# php skip a variable when calling a function

Tags: php, function

Lets say I have this code:

```
<?php 
function sayHello($forename = 'John', $lastname = 'doe') {
    return 'Hello '.$forename . ' ' . $lastname;
}
?>
```

if I call this function like:

```
sayHello();
```

it returns

> Hello John doe

but what if my first name is correct and I want to change only my lastname?

I can't do this:

```
sayHello(,,'lastname')
```

is there a way to leave the firstname alone and only change the lastname?

Comment: You can't, unfortunately.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620737/using-default-value-when-calling-a-function, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597114/php-default-function-parameter-values-how-to-pass-default-value-for-not-last, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968965/php-default-arguments, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978929/php-function-with-optional-parameters, https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20default%20function%20arguments+site:stackoverflow.com