# PHP default arguments, can you pick and choose?

Tags: php

In C# you can pick and choose your parameters by name, like so:

```
public void Foo(int b = 0, int a = 1, int r = 2) {
    print(b + ", " + a + ", " r);
}

Foo( b: 1, r: 7 );
```

which would result in the numbers

> 1, 1, 7

being printed out, skipping the default variable "A".

I was wondering if this was possible in php, because passing the default value when you don't need to use it seems redundant.

Comment: have you tried func_get_args ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Comment: This is a duplicate to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066625/how-would-i-skip-optional-arguments-in-a-function-call But to answer your question anyway: No, you can only skip arguments at the end of your list.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968965/php-default-arguments